# Linear system of equations for parking lot lighting

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a parking lot with dimensions $20 m \times 30 m$ which is illuminated by lights placed in different positions and heights as shown below:

[image: Parking lot]

The parking is divided into a rectangular grid of 600 squares. Let $y_j$ be the "light level" in square $j$, $j=0,\dots ,599$. Let $x_i$ be the "light intensity" of lamp $i$. The contribution of each lamp to the light level of each square is $\frac{x_i}{d_{ij}^2}$ where $d_{ij}$ is the distance in $\mathbb{R}^3$ from the lamp to the *center* of square $j$.

I want to do the following:

1. Create a linear system of equations that relates $y=(y_0 ,\dots ,y_{599})$ and $x=(x_0 ,\dots , x_{11})$ and find the coefficient matrix for the system. I will just estimate the position of each lamp from the figure above.
2. Find the light level in each square when all lamps have $x_i=1$.

**Progress:**

I have that

$
y_j=\frac{x_i}{d_{ij}}
$

Comment: @rschwieb Title updated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than numbering the squares $0..599$, introduce two-dimensional indices $m=0..19;n=0..29$ which correspond to the lower left corners of the squares (in meters).

The center $c_{mn}$ of square in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is:

$$c_{mn} = ({m+0.5;n+0.5;0})$$

The squared distance between lamp $i$ at point $(p_{ix};p_{iy};p_{iz})$ and center $c_{mn}$:

$$d_{imn}^2 = (p_{ix} - m - 0.5)^2 + (p_{iy} - n - 0.5)^2 + p_{iz}^2$$

The brightness or intensity as sum of light contributions at center $c_{mn}$ is [proportional](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90825) to:

$$y_{mn} = \sum_{i=0}^{11}\frac{x_i}{d_{imn}^2}$$

If a one-dimensional index of the squares is required, you can calculate $m$ and $n$:

$$m = j \mod{20}$$
$$n = \left\lfloor\frac{j}{30}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Yes, arranging the $y$ into a matrix is more manageable (+1), however that implies a 3D matrix

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question. You need to create a system of linear equations such that:

$ X D = Y $

D is a $ 600 \times 30 $ matrix containing all the distances between the lamps and the squares, $ Y = \left ( y_{0}, y_{1}, y_{2}, ... ,y_{599} \right ) $ and $ X = \left ( x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, ... ,x_{11} \right ) $

Eller du kunne skrive til en af dine instruktorer :')